# Mysql updates based on time?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way automatically update some tuples based on time. 
I have a field that I would like to increment every week from the time stored for that particular row.
Say I have two tuples with date and count fields:
2000-01-02     10
2000-01-03     1

Is it possible to automatically increment the count field every week from the stored date?
So that the first row is incremented on 2000-01-09 and the second row is incremented on 2000-01-10 and this would be done weekly.

Or in general can I update something automatically based on some time gone by?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a cron task in linux or a scheduled task in windows that executes a query on the db

Comment: yeah cron or crontab a php file

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Are these methods easy to implement? I'm relatively new to mysql and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store an extra field: `next_increment_date`.

Then you update regularly (say, once per hour or day...  or however often makes sense):

```
UPDATE my_table
  SET next_increment_date = DATE_ADD( next_increment_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK ),
      count = count + 1
  WHERE next_increment_date <= NOW();
```

Comment: Hi Paddy, thank you for the response. From my understanding, this query updates both count and next_increment_date to the next time that I should increment. But it does not do this automatically correct?

Comment: That's right.  One way or another, you are going to have to schedule this query to be run regularly.  Via cron, MySQL event scheduler, or some other mechanism.  If you don't want to store an extra date field, you'll need a query that is run once every day and only updates `count` if the current day (monday, tuesday etc) matches that of the stored date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the event scheduler:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html